# ClassMode cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: spring-mvc, junit

In my java spring mvc app, I am trying to reset a bunch of records for test with Junit.
but in line:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

It complains with:

```
ClassMode cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Update:

I have added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

but then it complains with other lines

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(scripts="requests-dataset.sql") 
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

the error is:

```
    ActiveProfiles cannot be resolved to a type
Sql cannot be resolved to a type
Sql cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the class name is DirtiesContext.ClassMode (it's a nested class of DirtiesContext).

Second, as any other class, it must be imported.

Third, as the [javadoc shows](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.ClassMode.html), it exists since Spring 3.0. So you won't find it in Spring 2.5. Use the same version of spring-test as the version used for the rest of the spring framework libraries that you're using.